# Visualizing Information from each layer: Reconstructing images with Feature Maps

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I'm interested in visualizing information from a particular layer of the model. In this instance I'm using a **pytorch** model for **ResNet18** source code for which can be found [here](https://pytorch.org/vision/0.8/_modules/torchvision/models/resnet.html).

Essentially the idea is to get the information each layer has for any input image that it is being trained on, and reconstruct the input image with the information that particular Conv Layer contains for the input image with the feature maps. For example, if a convolutional layer with with Nth filter corresponding to a Dogs Ear, I'd like to be able to view which CNN layer corresponds to which attribute of the image.

A given input image vector x is encoded
in each layer of the CNN by the filter responses to that image. A layer with N distinct filters
has Nl feature maps each of size Ml, where Ml is the height times the width of the feature map.

Passing the data via the pytorch dataloaders:

```
data_transforms = {
    'train': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.RandomResizedCrop(224),
        transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ]),
    'val': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize(256),
        transforms.CenterCrop(224),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ]),
}

data_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Animal Data/'
image_datasets = {x: datasets.ImageFolder(os.path.join(data_dir, x),
                                          data_transforms[x])
                  for x in ['train', 'val']}
dataloaders = {x: torch.utils.data.DataLoader(image_datasets[x], batch_size=4,
                                             shuffle=True, num_workers=4)
              for x in ['train', 'val']}
dataset_sizes = {x: len(image_datasets[x]) for x in ['train', 'val']}
class_names = image_datasets['train'].classes

device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
```

I'm training the model here:

```
def train_model(model, criterion, optimizer, scheduler, num_epochs=25):
    since = time.time()

    best_model_wts = copy.deepcopy(model.state_dict())
    best_acc = 0.0

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        print(f'Epoch {epoch}/{num_epochs - 1}')
        print('-' * 10)

        # Each epoch has a training and validation phase
        for phase in ['train', 'val']:
            if phase == 'train':
                model.train()  # Set model to training mode
            else:
                model.eval()   # Set model to evaluate mode

            running_loss = 0.0
            running_corrects = 0

            # Iterate over data.
            for inputs, labels in dataloaders[phase]:
                inputs = inputs.to(device)
                labels = labels.to(device)

                # zero the parameter gradients
                optimizer.zero_grad()

                # forward
                # track history if only in train
                with torch.set_grad_enabled(phase == 'train'):
                    outputs = model(inputs)
                    _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)
                    loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

                    # backward + optimize only if in training phase
                    if phase == 'train':
                        loss.backward()
                        optimizer.step()

                # statistics
                running_loss += loss.item() * inputs.size(0)
                running_corrects += torch.sum(preds == labels.data)
            if phase == 'train':
                scheduler.step()

            epoch_loss = running_loss / dataset_sizes[phase]
            epoch_acc = running_corrects.double() / dataset_sizes[phase]

            print(f'{phase} Loss: {epoch_loss:.4f} Acc: {epoch_acc:.4f}')

            # deep copy the model
            if phase == 'val' and epoch_acc > best_acc:
                best_acc = epoch_acc
                best_model_wts = copy.deepcopy(model.state_dict())

        print()

    time_elapsed = time.time() - since
    print(f'Training complete in {time_elapsed // 60:.0f}m {time_elapsed % 60:.0f}s')
    print(f'Best val Acc: {best_acc:4f}')

    # load best model weights
    model.load_state_dict(best_model_wts)
    return model
```

I understand that I likely have to work with the model itself, but I'm lost on how I'd begin doing that. Any tips, or sources are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you search and read about PyTorch hooks, you can use hooks to observe the input and the output of any layer in the network, and then you can call a function to construct what you want.
You can start by reading the documentation about it, you can find it [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html?highlight=hook#torch.nn.Module.register_forward_hook). The idea is that you should hook a function to a layer and this function will receive the input and the output of this layer and inside this function, you will write your code to construct what you want.

Comment: That would be exactly what I'm looking for, I'll look into it. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

as Hatem said, I think Pytorch Hooks are the best option for you. In my case I only wanted to see the activation maps from the last layer and I used this hook:

```
feature_blobs = []

def hook_feature(module, input, output):
     feature_blobs.append(output.data.cpu().numpy())

# 'layer4' is the name of the ResNet18 layer I wanted to watch but you can choose any
model._modules.get('layer4').register_forward_hook(hook_feature)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, I got it working perfectly! I wasn't aware of the existence of hooks before, this makes it quite simple to use.